# How to get CSS overflow & height:calc to work in a resizable div

Tags: css, vue.js

I am using vue-grid-layout, which provides x number of divs. Each div is resizable by dragging the icon on its bottom right corner.

I am trying to split the div into 3 logical parts. I want to have

- a top portion of fixed height,
- a variable middle portion, and
- a bottom portion of fixed height

I am having trouble containing the middle portion in it's own space. It seems to spill over no matter what I do.  It doesn't seem that adding an overflow:auto and height:calc(100%-topHeight+bottomHeight) to the style of the middle div works as expected.  As an added bonus, I'm not sure I know the height of the parent div as they are resizable and calculated from the grid-layout/grid-item components.

I have a demonstration in the following fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/uglyhobbitfeet/gs2qf3t6/1/

Below is the main block of code that I am trying to get to work.

```
'            <v-layout secondary>',
'              <v-flex xs12>',
'                <div style="height:25px;background-color:green">TOP</div>',
'              </v-flex>',
'              <v-flex xs12 style="height:calc(100%-50px);overflow:auto;">',
'                <div style="height:125px;background-color:blue">MIDDLE</div>',
'              </v-flex>',    
'              <v-flex xs12>',
'                <div style="height:25px;background-color:red">BOTTOM</div>',
'              </v-flex>',
'            </v-layout>',
```

Comment: You have an error in your fiddle. You need to add spaces in your calc: `height: calc(100% - 50px);`
What I would suggest though would be adding flex to v-layout:
`display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;`

Comment: Hi, that comes close, but there's still a few issues. I expect the first 3 boxes to have scrollbars and the last one to shrink down so there's no gray space. Updated example is here https://jsfiddle.net/uglyhobbitfeet/gs2qf3t6/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with [Flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/je4uzgv5/6/) or [Grid](https://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/pedwqfms/4/) layouts. The markup is the same for both and neither relies on known heights or calcs.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="body-content">Body</div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

#### Option 1: Flex CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

header,
footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

#### Option 2: Grid CSS

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "header" auto
    "body" 1fr
    "footer" auto;
}

.body {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added your suggestion to the fiddle but it still doesn't seem right. Please double-check that I entered it as you suggested. https://jsfiddle.net/uglyhobbitfeet/gs2qf3t6/4/

Comment: Your structure is deeper nested than my simple example. You just have to keep following it till everything that needs flex on it, has it. https://jsfiddle.net/vxrwkdao/

Comment: It seems to work now if I add another div inside the middle and set the height there. https://jsfiddle.net/uglyhobbitfeet/5vL6k7ma/20/